# Como poner 1 borde especifico en css

Tags: css

La idea es tener un borde que recubra por ejemplo un h3 , pero únicamente tenga borde por arriba y los laterales.

Es decir, que abajo no tenga línea de borde.

Es posible con css y php ?

Comment: Jorge, la respuesta a tu pregunta es si. Pero recuerda que debes agregar a tu pregunta un ejemplo mínimo de tu código para facilitar la ayuda. Haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas la observación que te hago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `CSS` tienes la propiedad `border` y puedes usarla independiente para cada lado con `border-top:`, `border-right:`, `border-bottom:`, `border-left:`.

Por ejemplo, puedes especificar el grosor del borde `1px`, el estilo de la línea `solid`, `dashed`, `dotted` y el color `#ff0000`.

Lo puedes usar así:

```css
h3 {
  border-top: 1px solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 2px dashed #f0f000;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 5px dotted #09f000;
}
```

```html
<h3>Título</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución

```css
h3 {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-bottom: 0;
}
```